# How can I break a color box out of a Bootstrap container element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

So I've tried a few of the solutions provided here (and elsewhere on the web) to see if I could break out of the bootstrap container, but I'm not having any luck.  To describe it, I have a `.fluid-container` to put a full-width background behind a normal `.container`.   Where things get tricky is that I need the first column in `.container` to break out and extend all the way to the left edge of the screen.

What it should look like:

[image]

What I've gotten it to do:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-darkblue bg-image-footer py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="footer-content">
                <div class="col-5 px-0 py-3 bg-limegreen">
                    Form content goes here.
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-2 text-white">
                    <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-upper">Contact Us</p>
                    <p>(202) 555-1212</p>
                    <p>email@email.com</p>
                    <p>New York, NY</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-upper">Client Name</p>
                    <p>About</p>
                    <p>Careers</p>
                    <p>Accessibility</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-upper">Social</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To reiterate -- the goal here is to move the left edge of the lime green box all the way to the left edge of the screen, without moving the right edge out of the grid system or screwing with the rest of the layout.

All CSS is straightforward Bootstrap 5, with the exception of a few things to control color like `.bg-limegreen`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap layouts should never have immediately-nested containers. Instead, use standard row/column nesting. Avoid trying to "break out" of anything unless you actually need overlap across columns. That's rarely the case.

Also note that I replaced some of your custom classes with existing Bootstrap classes (`text-light` and `text-uppercase`). You'd be wise to get to know what Bootstrap offers very well to avoid building redundant CSS technical debt. See Bootstrap's [text utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/).

I'd also encourage you to override Bootstrap's [semantically-named](https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/) classes for color rather than creating new, non-semantic ones. For example, `text-limegreen` might instead be an override of `text-success`, even if just for the footer. Have a look at Bootstrap's [color utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/colors).

```css
.bg-darkblue {
  background: darkblue;
}

.bg-limegreen {
  background: limegreen;
}

.text-limegreen {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-darkblue bg-image-footer py-5">
  <div class="row" id="footer-content">
    <div class="col-5 px-0 py-3 bg-limegreen">
      <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-8 text-light">
          Form content goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1"></div>

    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row justify-content-start text-light pt-2">
        <div class="col-3">
          <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-uppercase">Contact Us</p>
          <p>(202) 555-1212</p>
          <p>email@email.com</p>
          <p>New York, NY</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-uppercase">Client Name</p>
          <p>About</p>
          <p>Careers</p>
          <p>Accessibility</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
          <p class="avenir text-limegreen text-uppercase">Social</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  I appreciate the feedback re: learning bootstrap better, but can we focus on the request rather than answering philosophically?  Thanks.

Comment: How is a specific code demo "philosophical"?